# What is this "iif" in php means?

Tags: php, syntax

Has anyone see this "iif" in php before? What is that actually? I try to search the documentation for it in php.net but I cant found any. Anyone can give a simple example of how to use this "iif"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is part of PHPKit. It stands for [Immediate If](http://youropensource.com/projects/64-IIF-function).

The syntax is:

```
iif(condition, true statement, false statement);
```

@VolkerK's comment should be noted: "And keep in mind that iff(x,y,z) evaluates both y and z (no lazy function parameter evaluation in php) while x?y:z evaluates only y or z."

Comment: CIOCCHI I PIATTI?

Comment: Hi @Skilldrick, Immediate If link now is broken.

Answer (score 12):

The function `iif` does not exist in the standard PHP libraries. But in most cases it is a 'short if expression' such as: `(condition ? true : false)`.

Comment: That’s an expression and not a statement.

Comment: And keep in mind that iff(x,y,z) evaluates both y and z (no lazy function parameter evaluation in php) while x?y:z evaluates only y or z.

Answer (score 1):

copied from http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=124215.0

```
function iff($tst,$cmp,$bad) {
    return(($tst == $cmp)?$cmp:$bad);
}

echo iff('one','two','three');
echo iff('four','four','ok');
```