# PHP If-Else-Finally

Tags: php, if-statement

I am looking for smarter way of solving what I have called *if-else-finally* case.

**The Case**
According to different conditions the object's property requires different value. Only if this property has been changed persist the object to DB.

**The example** (pseudocode)

```
if _condition-A_ then
    set object.property to value-A
else if _condition-B_ then
    set object.property to value-B
else if _condition-C_ then
    set object.property to value-C
finally
    object.persist()
```

**My solution**

```
$changed = false;
if ($conditionA) {
    $changed = true;
    $this->property = 'A';
} elseif ($conditionB) {
    $changed = true;
    $this->property = 'B';
} elseif ($conditionC) {
    $changed = true;
    $this->property = 'C';
}
if ($changed) {
    $this->save();
}
```

**Is there any better/smarter solution for this?** The `switch-case-default` construct is not possible as the conditions are compounded from smaller partial conditions that differ in each `if` statement.

Comment: Thats exactly how I do it too.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately I am afraid there is no other solution... But I'd like to stop repeating `$changed = true;` over and over.

Comment: you can always do `switch(true)` and put the conditions in each case

Comment: You could possibly store the current value before your set of if statements and then check to see if the value has changed afterwards

Comment: @Jonathon Yes, this could help to get rid of repeating `$changed = true;` but still I need the last `if` statement... But I can save few lines of code, so that's a nice hint!

Comment: Yeah, it's unfortunate PHP doesn't seem to have something similar to finally.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can avoid repeating `$changed = true;` by this way :

```
$changed = true;
if ($conditionA) {
    $this->property = 'A';
} elseif ($conditionB) {
    $this->property = 'B';
} elseif ($conditionC) {
    $this->property = 'C';
} else {
    $changed = false;
}
if ($changed) {
    $this->save();
}
```

Comment: This is good i have a doubt whether Ternary operator can be used for this logic or you think it is just a over kill of ternary operator usage

Comment: Hmm, nice, looks like the best solution provided. @NaveenThally: ternary operators are nice and kind of readable if you condition like `$a = $b ? : $c`; but **never** if you have something like: `$a = $b && $c && !$d ? 'Yes Yes!' : $e + $f > $g && $h && !$i ? 'Uhm, OK' : sqrt($j) < 10 && $k - $l < $m && ($n || $o) ? 'Oh com'on!' : 'No WAY!!!';`

Comment: @shadyyx thank you buddy, for readibility and for codevelopers to understand its better, this would be perfect solution, instead of ternary operator

Comment: @NaveenThally I have added another answer here that tells something about ternary operators... Take a look if you want :-)

Answer (score 2):

I just played with php `array`

```
if ( $property = array_search( true, array(
    'A' => $conditionA ,
    'B' => $conditionB ,
    'C' => $conditionC 
)) ){
    $this->property = $property;
    $this->save();
};
```

Comment: This seems to be useful at least because it shortens the code but it may become unreadable with really complicated conditions...

Answer (score 1):

Though this is not a real answer for my question (as I already accepted one), I wanted to post here some thoughts on using ternary operators and using here mentioned *third-party* `iif` function.

This `iif` stands for *[Immediate if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092642/what-is-this-iif-in-php-means)* and it's [implementation](http://youropensource.com/projects/64-IIF-function) **could** be this:

```
function iif($condition, $true, $false) {
    return ($condition ? $true : $false);
}
```

I am telling *could* because it is not a native part of PHP and if you want to use it, you need to define it somewhere globally and it is completely up to you how you define it, maybe even

```
function iif($condition, $true, $false) {
    return ($condition && $true ? true : $false);
}
```

(just for example). So one cannot be never sure what that stinky `iif` does in the end. As you can see, this `iif` can use *[ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)* successfully, and it is in the end much predictable to use them directly. Therefore instead of running this *black-box*

```
$this->property = iif($conditionA, // what does this 'iif' do???
    'A',
    iif($conditionB, // what does this 'iif' do???
        'B',
        iif($conditionC, // what does this 'iif' do???
            'C','NONE')));
```

it is much brighter (when it comes to light conditions) to use

```
$this->property = $conditionA // ok, if matches then 'A'
    ? 'A'
    : $conditionB // ok, if matches then 'B'
        ? 'B'
        : $conditionC // ok, if matches then 'C' otherwise 'D'
            ? 'C'
            : 'D';
```

As you can see usage of ternary operators can be more readable and predictable even if they are used *recursively*.

And now I want to show you how can such complicated ternary operator be created. Imagine that you are doing a download of data into a CSV (`;` seprarated) file. You have to filter only the columns for CSV within the retrieved data and optionally `trim` the value if it exists. The ternary is quite simple:

```
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $row[] = array_key_exists($field, $item) // if field is present and contains value trim it
        ? trim($item[$field])))
        : ''; // otherwise use empty string
}
```

This is running fine for a while until somebody comes and tells you that he wants to have *Yes*/*No* displayed instead of *1*/*0* in two columns. So, OK, no big deal, let's just slightly modify this condition:

```
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $row[] = array_key_exists($field, $item) // if field is present and contains value
        ? ($field == 'col1' || $field == 'col2' // if it is a 'col1' or 'col2' field
            ? ($item[$field] ? 'Yes' : 'No') // display 'Yes'/'No'
            : trim($item[$field])) // otherwise trim the value
        : ''; // otherwise use empty string
}
```

OK... Now it is little bit complicated since we added one more level and the true expression of the inner level contains another ternary. And what if the same guy comes again and tells you to add two new columns, which can have values `NULL`, `0` and `1` and for each you have to display either `''`, `No` or `Yes`? Well, then it could look like this one:

```
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $row[] = array_key_exists($field, $item)
        ? ($field == 'col1' || $field == 'col2'
            ? ($item[$field] ? 'Yes' : 'No')
            : ($field == 'col1_1' || $field == 'col2_2'
                ? ($item[$field] === 1 ? 'Yes' : $item[$field] === 0 ? 'No' : '')
                :trim($item[$field])))
        : '';
}
```

Here, at this point, I stopped for a while and started thinking about rewriting into `if-else` which would have more readability but I would have to write it all in more lines which I didn't want to do either. The code isn't that much confusing, it is nicely structured so that everybody sees where the new *recursion* starts and ends. But this is possible only since the conditions themselves are quite simple and single-layered.

In case of more complicated conditions for each ternary I would avoid using ternary operators and stick to `if-else` to preserve readability.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a map of the conditions to the property value.

Example of the concept:

```
$conditionA = false;
$conditionB = true;
$conditionC = false;

$conditions = [
  'conditionA' => 'A',
  'conditionB' => 'B',
  'conditionC' => 'C'
];

foreach($conditions as $conditionName => $conditionValue) {
    if (!empty($$conditionName)) {
        $this->property = $conditionValue;
        $this->save();
        break;
    } 
}
```

Comment: That's an example of what I meant by mapping, not proper code, as I do not know how you plan to implement it. If you'd like a prettier version, see @rab version, which should be the accepted answer by the way.

Comment: As written in the comment to @Rab's answer, it can become unreadable as well. The shortening of code shouldn't make the code unreadable nor confusing which could easily happen with such solutions.

Comment: This seems a better and smarter way +1 from me I don't know what OP looks for