# PHP shortcut for if stament

Tags: php

I'm currently learning PHP and I found a bit of code I hope someone would help me explain. I use it for when there is an error in a form input, so the input won't be empty after refresh, but contain the user's input from before he/she pressed submit.

PHP Part

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $checkUsername = null; // just in case
  $checkUsername = $_POST['username'];
};
```

HTML Part

```
<form method="post">
   <label for="username" class="control-label">Username</label>
   <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter username" value="<?php echo !empty($checkUsername)?$checkUsername:'';?>"> 
   <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create user</button>
</form>
```

The "shortcut" I don't get is:

```
<?php echo !empty($checkUsername)?$checkUsername:'';?>
```

The way i normally would do this is:

```
if(!empty($checkUsername)){
   echo $checkUsername;
}else{
   echo "";
};
```

Is there a webpage where I can look up this kind of shortcut?

Comment: You could use `echo !empty($chckusername) ? $checkUsername : ''`. [Have a look here](https://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples).

Comment: Makes me wonder you guys are busy answering already answered questions like this one. Could lookup this SO answer about PHP [Immediate IF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092642/what-is-this-iif-in-php-means).

Comment: The if-?-: syntax is: if <condition> ? <action if condition is true> : <action if condition is false>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called `Ternary Operator`

The way you use it often start with a language construct, variable assignment, or just plain expression statement.

> Examples:
>
> $a = $b === 3 ? 1 : 2; // if b equals to 3, $a will be
>   assigned as 1 else 2
>
> match() ? go_forward() : go_backward(); // this
>   calls a match function and if the return value evaluates to true then
>   it will call `go_forward` function else it calls `go_backward`
>   function

Here is a little part describe from the official website, [Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

> From php version 5.3 onward,
>
> you can also use it in the expression as `expr1 ?: expr3`, where it
>   returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise

Answer (score 2):

use ternary operators for this

```
echo !empty($checkUsername) ? $checkUsername : "";
```

Its equivallent to

```
if(!empty($checkUsername)){
   echo $checkUsername;
}else{
    echo "";
}
```

See [this](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) and [this](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
echo (!empty($checkUsername)) ? $checkUsername: '';
```

It works as `"(condition) ? (true return value) : (false return value)"` statements to shorten your if/else structures.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo !empty($checkUsername)?$checkUsername:'';?>
```

This is a ternary operator. You could read more about them in [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

You can write this condition more shorter

```
<?= $checkUsername ?: '';?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called a Ternary Operator: `statement 1 ? statement 2 : statement 3`
Statement 1 is evaluated, if it's true resolve to statement 2 else resolve to statement 3.

You will see it in more languages than just PHP, their difficult to read at first but a convenient shorthand later.